# Contact numbers for historic shuls in Upstate NY

Tags: synagogue, chutz-laaretz

There are several shuls in upstate NY, esp. in the Catskills region, that are on the Historical registry. When I visited some of these last summer, they were closed, and I could not locate any phone numbers for them on the web, and info (Verizon) did not have a number either. I'm curious if any of these shuls are active on any level, whether during the summer or Rosh Hashannah / Yom Kippur. The specific shuls I'm interested in are in these towns, all in NY State:

- Spring Glen
- Mountaindale
- Parksville
- Tupper Lake (I think the name is    Bet Joseph)

If anyone knows if any of these are active and / or has a number of someone whom I can contact, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can contact:

The Catskills Institute
c/o Phil Brown
Department of Sociology
Brown University, Box 1916
Providence, RI 02912
401-863-2367

They should be able to assist you.

Regarding Tupper Lake. They are open in July & August. You can contact: Janet Chapman @
518-359-9594.

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't think of the Catskill Institute. I had seen some of their articles on the web a while ago. Nicely organized. How did you find the # & name of the Tupper Lake shul?

Comment: Called the Tupper Lake #, yesterday. Spoke to Janet. They are open summer only T-Th 11-3 & services Fri. night at 7p. They jost got a new rabbi. Thanks, Gershon, again, for the info. It's perfect!